# What is the use of logging menu in settings

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

What is the use / purpose  of  logging menu in the

```
Settings -> Technical -> Database structure -> Logging
```

Comment: This question is about a function / configuration in a software and is not about programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you can store all the log messages in that view (model `ir.logging`) as long as you use the parameter `--log-db your_database_name` when executing `odoo-bin` in the command line (or add `log_db = your_database_name` in your Odoo config file).

Check out Odoo 11 info about command line parameters: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/cmdline.html

> **--log-db**
>
> logs to the ir.logging model (ir_logging table) of the specified database. The database can be the name of a database in the “current” PostgreSQL, or a PostgreSQL URI for e.g. log aggregation

This is the theory, but honestly, I was not able to make it work, and I did not waste much time in trying to know why.

**EDIT**

As @CZoellner says, it seems that log messages stored in `ir_logging` table (log messages you see clicking on the menuitem *Settings -> Technical -> Database structure -> Logging*) come only from scheduled actions. If you create an scheduled action which executes some Python code, you have the following available variables to use in your method code:

- `env`: Odoo Environment on which the action is triggered.
- `model`: Odoo Model of the record on which the action is triggered; is a void recordset.
- `record`: record on which the action is triggered; may be void.
- `records`: recordset of all records on which the action is triggered in multi-mode; may be void.
- `time`, `datetime`, `dateutil`, `timezone`: useful Python libraries.
- `log`: `log(message, level='info')`: logging function to record debug information in `ir.logging` table.
- `Warning`: Warning Exception to use with raise To return an action, assign: action = {...}.

If you use the `log` one, for example:

```
log('This message will be stored in ir_logging table', level='critical')
```

That log message and its details will be stored in `ir_logging` table each time the scheduled action is executed (automatically or manually). This answers your question, but now I am wondering what is the parameter `--log-db`, as I have tested it and these log messages are stored in `ir_logging` no matter this parameter is set or not.

Comment: Isn't that just used for logging in scheduled actions and automated actions?

Comment: It seems that you are right, I have edited the answer but now I do not know what is `--log-db` for.